# How to calculate multiple averages using nested for loop?

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate multiple averages using a nested for loop. The inner one works fine on its own but when I tried nesting it inside an outer for loop with to calculate multiple students the program displays the first average correctly but beyond that, the program doesn't calculate the average. Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    int ctr = 0, i, mark, grades, s, students;
    float average, gradeTotal = 0, mark;

    printf("how many students?\n");
    scanf("%i", &students);

    for (s = 1; s <= students; s++)
    {
        printf("Enter number of grades:\n");
        scanf("%f", &grades);

        for (i = 1; i <= grades; i++)
        {
            printf("enter mark: \n");
            scanf("%i", &mark);

            gradeTotal += mark;
        }
        average = gradeTotal/grades;
        printf("The average is %.2f\n", average);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Reinitialise `gradeTotal`  to zero at the start of the outer loop.  Without that, the printed average will be the total across the current students AND all preceding students divided by `grades`, whereas you want the average for EACH student.

Comment: It's now working! Thanks so much Peter!

Comment: @Peter, post it as answer as I don't wanna take the credit for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix is to reinitialise `gradeTotal` to zero at the start of the outer loop.

Without that, `gradeTotal` will keep a running total for all students, so the printed value will be that running total for the current students AND all preceding students, divided by `grades`, whereas you want the average for EACH student.

You may wish to also consider limiting scope of the variables.   For example, defining AND initialising `gradeTotal` within the outer loop (rather than defining it outside the loop) will prevent any chance of accidentally misusing its values between loop iterations as you have.    As a general rule, it is better to define variables in the smallest scope possible, since that helps eliminate problems such as forgetting to reinitialise while preventing accidental use in other code.  `mark` and `i` are not needed outside the inner loop. `s`, `grades`, `gradeTotal`, and `average` are not needed outside the outer loop.  `ctr` is not needed at all.